# Simple framework. Do not serialize some variables to xml

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I have problem serializing java object to XML. My classes are shown below:

```
@Root(strict = false, name = "Detail")
public class ProductList {
    @ElementList(inline = true, entry = "Product")
    private List<Product> products;
}

@Root(strict = false)
public class Product {
    @Element(name = "ProductCode")
    private String productCode;
    @Element(name = "ProductPrice")
    private double productPrice;
    @Element(name = "Currency")
    private String currency;
    @Element(name = "ConversionRate")
    private int conversionRate;
    @Element(name = "ProductPoints", required = false)
    private int productPoints;
    @Element(name = "ProductCount", required = false)
    private int productCount;
    @Element(name = "ProductName", required = false)
    private String productName;
    @Element(name = "MinPrice", required = false)
    private double minPricet;
    @Element(name = "MaxPrice", required = false)
    private double maxPricet;
    @Element(name = "CanChangePrice", required = false)
    private String canChangePrice;
}
```

The XML below is sent from server and it's *deserialized* without any problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Detail>
  <Product>
    <ProductCode>0001</ProductCode>
    <ProductPrice>0.90</ProductPrice>
    <Currency>GEL</Currency>
    <ConversionRate>200</ConversionRate>
    <ProductName>Bread</ProductName>
    <MinPrice>0.9</MinPrice>
    <MaxPrice>0.9</MaxPrice>
    <CanChangePrice>N</CanChangePrice>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    ...
  </Product>
</Detail>
```

I try to generate the XML document that will have this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Detail>
  <Product>
    <ProductCode>0001</ProductCode>
    <ProductPrice>0.90</ProductPrice>
    <Currency>GEL</Currency>
    <ConversionRate>200</ConversionRate>
    <ProductPoints>180</ProductPoints>
    <ProductCount>1</ProductCount>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    ...
  </Product>
</Detail>
```

But I get this:

```
<Detail>
   <Product>
      <ProductCode>0001</ProductCode>
      <ProductPrice>0.9</ProductPrice>
      <Currency>GEL</Currency>
      <ConversionRate>200</ConversionRate>
      <productPoints>180</productPoints>
      <ProductCount>1</ProductCount>
      <ProductName>Bread</ProductName>
      <MinPrice>0.9</MinPrice>
      <MaxPrice>0.9</MaxPrice>
      <CanChangePrice>N</CanChangePrice>
   </Product>
   <Product>
      ...
   </Product>
</Detail>
```

Tags `<ProductName>`, `<MinPrice>`, `<MaxPrice>`, `<CanChangePrice>` mustn't be included in the serialized XML.

**Is there any way I can tell the framework not to include specific tags\variables while serializing?**

Comment: What framework do you use? Did you write it yourself? How are you trying to generate the XML? Please post the relevant code.

Comment: The framework I use is called ['Simple'](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

Your class members are *not*  initialized to `null` and so `required=false` has not the effect of *not*  serializing them.

`int`s are serialized by [`org.simpleframework.xml.transform.IntegerTransform`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/report/cobertura/org.simpleframework.xml.transform.IntegerTransform.html). The `write(Integer)` method of this class is simple:

```
public String write(Integer value) {
   return value.toString();
}
```

As you can see, simple autoboxing is used.

1. Your primitive `int` is initialized to `0` by the constructor.
2. It is boxed into an `Integer`.
3. The `String` value of this `Integer` is `"0"` which is *not* `null`.

### Solution

Use `Integer`, not `int` for your class members.

### Edit

If you don't want to serialize a member, don't annotate it with `@Element`. Simple is not about 'generating' XML but about mapping instances to/from XML. Every member you want to map needs an annotation. Every member with an annotation will be mapped.

Comment: My problem is that I do not want the last 4 tags to be included inside `<Product>` element. Updated the question

Comment: If I don't annotate the member variables with `@Element`, they don't get initialized after XML deserialization.

Comment: I want to map all tags from XML to Java. But exclude some tags when mapping from Java to XML.

Comment: @gkiko I can't see how this is possible. Mapping is a two-way operation.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pretty ugly. I created another class for XML serialization, that contains every field from the original class except the fields I wanted to omit in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can override default serialization mechanism with [converter](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#converters) to customize the output. For example that you provide it will be:

```
public class CustomProductConverter implements Converter<Product> {

    private void createProductPropertyNode(OutputNode productNode, String propertyName, String value) throws Exception {
        productNode.getChild(propertyName).setValue(value);
    }

    private void createProductPropertyNode(OutputNode productNode, String propertyName, int value) throws Exception {
        createProductPropertyNode(productNode, propertyName, String.valueOf(value));
    }

    private void createProductPropertyNode(OutputNode productNode, String propertyName, double value) throws Exception {
        createProductPropertyNode(productNode, propertyName, String.valueOf(value));
    }

    @Override
    public Product read(InputNode inputNode) throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode outputNode, Product product) throws Exception {
        createProductPropertyNode(outputNode, "ProductCode"   , product.getProductCode());
        createProductPropertyNode(outputNode, "ProductPrice"  , product.getProductPrice());
        createProductPropertyNode(outputNode, "Currency"      , product.getCurrency());
        createProductPropertyNode(outputNode, "ConversionRate", product.getConversionRate());
        createProductPropertyNode(outputNode, "ProductPoints" , product.getProductPoints());
        createProductPropertyNode(outputNode, "ProductCount"  , product.getProductCount());

        outputNode.commit();
    }
}
```

And then use a **RegistryStrategy** for serialization:

```
Registry registry = new Registry();
registry.bind(Product.class, CustomProductConverter.class);

Strategy strategy = new RegistryStrategy(registry);
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);

// serialize your object with serializer
```

**PROS**: you can dynamically serialize same object with different converters and get different output without modification of the model classes.

**CONS**: in the case of a complex model there will be a lot of similar code in converter.